# О значении слова модальный

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Мы часто употребляем его: модальные слова,  модальные глаголы, модальные отношения. Вот даже модальные обстоятельства встретились, а также слово "мода" считается однокоренным.

Скорее всего, во всех случаях один и тот же исторический (латинский) корень, но как с ним связать весь спектр указанных значений? Можно ли найти в этом списке какое-то единое начало, чтобы  дать однозначное определение  модальности?

Answer (score 3):

Толковый словарь Ушакова:

> 1. МОДА́ЛЬНЫЙ1, модальная, модальное (книжн.). прил. к модальность.
> 2. МОДА́ЛЬНЫЙ2, модальная, модальное (стат.). прил. к мода в 3 знач.; являющийся модой. Модальная величина.

Как видим, слово "мода"  однокоренное только для омонима - "являющийся модой". Что касается лингвистики, определение модальности есть во всех толковых словарях и справочниках.

Толковый словарь Ушакова:

> МОДА́ЛЬНОСТЬ, модальности, жен. (от ново-лат. modalis - прил. к modus,
> см. модус) (книжн.). Категория, выражающая **степень достоверности**
> суждения (филос.). || Грамматическая категория, обозначающая **отношение
> содержания речи к действительности**, напр. наклонение (линг.).

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/861990
Мода́льность (от лат. modus — мера, способ, наклонение)

Русская корпусная грамматика:

> Модальность – это понятийная категория, которая характеризует:
>
> а) **отношение говорящего к содержанию высказывания,**
>
> или б) **статус обозначенной в нем ситуации по отношению к реальному
> миру,**
>
> или в) иллокутивную силу, т.е. **коммуникативную цель говорящего**.
>
> **В грамматике модальность выражается, прежде всего, наклонением.** Например, в предложении Не уверен, что Маша пришла бы сослагательное
> наклонение выражает тот факт, что ситуация прихода Маши является
> гипотетической, а не реальной. В предложении Вот бы пришла Маша!
> сослагательное наклонение выражает желательность той же ситуации для
> говорящего. В предложении Уходи, Маша! повелительное наклонение
> выражает побуждение к действию.
>
> Модальные значения выражаются и многими другими способами –
> конструкциями (Быть бычку на веревочке), **вводными словами**
> (наверно), **модальными глаголами и предикативами (типа мочь, можно,
> нужно), частицами (все-таки) и проч.**

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%

То есть ***модальные слова в русском языке – это категория слов (чаще глаголов ), которые выражают не само действие, а отношение к нему, целевую установку, соответствие высказывания действительности.***

Модальность в русском языке выражается с помощью следующих лексических и грамматических средств:

1)наклонений: изъявительного, сослагательного и повелительного, а также с помощью независимого инфинитива (Уехать бы!);

2)вводно-модальных слов и модальных наречий: кажется, пожалуй, хочется;

3)модальных глаголов: хочу, нужно, можно, надо, должен, могу;

4)интонации.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за ответ. Я думаю, что он будет полезен нашим читателям, но я хотела бы услышать нечто философское на тему модальность (лат. modus)  как мера вещей.  В других областях науки (в философии, логике, психологии, математике, технике)  также используется это слово или однокоренные слова (модуль, модульный). Меня же интересовало определение в самом общем смысле.