# Модальные слова

Tags: скс

Задам вопрос еще раз, потому что ответа я так и не получила.

Является ли слово "скучно, грустно" и подобные им модальными словами?

*Например:*

Мне **грустно** смотреть на вас.
Мне **скучно** учить уроки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуем дать **другой ответ,** принцип Шарля Бали нам в помощь.

1. **Вводные слова и слова категории состояния**

Часть вводных слов относятся  к **оценочной модальной лексике**, то есть обозначают  **субъективную или объективную** модальность. *К радости, к счастью, к огорчению* — это оценка события с точки зрения говорящего.

2. ***Мне грустно, мне скучно*** — это **содержание** высказывания, а не оценка сказанного, модальности **здесь нет**.
3. *Мне грустно **смотреть на вас**. Мне скучно **учить уроки**.*

А вот здесь уже есть **оценка,** так как выражено **отношение** говорящего к действию. Не просто скучно и грустно, а грустно смотреть, скучно учить.

4. **Вывод**. Да, это оценочная **модальная** лексика, но только в **конкретных** предложениях. Сами по себе модальными словами они **не являются**, но могут **приобрести** модальность в заданных примерах.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
 я хотела бы услышать нечто философское на тему модальность 
 (лат. modus) как мера вещей. В других областях науки (в 
 философии, логике, психологии, математике, технике) также 
 используется это слово или однокоренные слова (модуль, 
 модульный). Меня же интересовало определение в самом общем 
 смысле.
```

**[О ФИЛОСОФИИ](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81+%28%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29)**

**Модус** — часть высказывания, отличная от **пропозиции** **(диктума)**. В каждом предложении есть два типа номинативных значений: **пропозиция и модус.** В пропозиции выражается суждение («положение дел» в мире), а в модусе — **отношение говорящего к данному суждению.**

Ср., например, *'**Я знаю**, что он прав', '**Я считаю**, что он прав', '**Мне кажется****, что он прав'*. В первом случае истинность пропозиции не ставится под сомнение **(модус знания);** во втором случае истинность пропозиции выводится логическим путём (**модус мнения**); в третьем высказывании истинность пропозиции **ставится под сомнение**, допускается альтернативный вариант. Таким образом, смысл высказывания определяется не только **номинативным планом, но и модальным планом.** Очевидно, что указанные высказывания могут использоваться в разных ситуациях и требуют разных контекстов, несмотря на совпадение пропозиций.

Разделять высказывание **на модус и диктум** впервые предложил [Шарль Балли](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D1%88%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&lr=213&clid=2270457&win=532&src=suggest_W) , внеся существенный вклад в трактовку **модальности в лингвистике.** Идея Ш.Балли позволила углубить знание лингвистической структуры высказывания как единицы речи и положила начало целому направлению, связанному **с разработкой классификации модусов.**

Балли взял термины **диктум** (лат. dictum — слово, выражение) и **модус** (лат. modus — способ) в схоластике и использовал их для обозначения **объективной и субъективной** части суждения.

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

*Мне **грустно** смотреть на вас. Мне **скучно** учить уроки.*

1. Сами по себе эти слова **категории состояния** модальными словами не являются, так как в них не модальной оценочности. Это обычное номинативное сообщение без указания отношения говорящего к своему сообщению.
2. Но они могут **прибрести модальное** значение в конкретном предложении:

*Мне **было бы** грустно смотреть на вас* (сослагательное наклонение).

*Мне **кажется,** что мне просто скучно учить уроки*
(**предположение**).

3. Но среди слов категории состояния есть **модальные** оценочные слова: ***жаль, обидно, нужно, лень и др.***

Подробно о модальности в **[теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462937/%D0%9E-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).** Там дана информация из **Русской корпусной грамматики** [http://rusgram.ru/Модальность](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)